# How to change default rendering strategy to JSON in ZF2?

Tags: zend-framework2

I create an API using ZF2. The server's response should contains only JSON. It should be only JSON if there is an error or 404 or 403 and in other cases.
Now, by default ZF2 is tryong to return HTML.
I use [ZendSkeletonApplication](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication)

Comment: What did you try so far? And what is your code?

Comment: I use zend skeleton application. I know how to return JSON in action controllers (return new JsonModel(...)). I want the application returns JSON always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ZF2 raises an error [by triggering specific events such as `MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR` or `MvcEvent::EVENT_RENDER_ERROR`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mvc.mvc-event.html#order-of-events) when an exception is thrown.

The `Zend\Mvc\View\Http\ExceptionStrategy` class attaches a number of listens to these events so the HTML error page can be generated.

To return a JSON error message you can attach a your own [custom exception strategy, with a higher priority, and check if the response should be JSON](http://akrabat.com/returning-json-errors-in-a-zf2-application/)

Answer (score 2):

In your controller, the easiest way is to return an instance of `Zend\View\Model\JsonModel`. For example:

```
$model = new JsonModel(array(
   'httpStatus' => 403,
   'title' => 'Forbidden',
   'message' => 'You are not authorized to access this page.'
));
return $model;
```

Comment: What if there is some exception throws on the server or requested page not found. Is it possible to return JSON in this cases?

Comment: You just need to catch the exception after routing, but I'm not sure where that happens- perhaps add a catch-all route?

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's a specific reason you chose the mvc skeleton app as a starting point, you might consider switching to https://apigility.org skeleton. This is also a ZF app, but it is built to be pure json api.